# Список из структур

Tags: unity3d, list, struct

У меня в первом скрипте есть 2 структуры:

```cs
public class Structs : MonoBehaviour
{
    public struct Homework
    {
        public int firstPage, secondPage;
        public string description;
        public bool done;
    }

    public struct User
    {
        public string userName, userSurname;
        public List<Homework> Homeworks;
    }
}
```

Первый дополняет второму, но это не суть.
Во втором скрипте у меня список из второй структуры.

```cs
public List<Structs.User> Users;
```

Я пытался добавить элемент в список Users:

```cs
Users.Add(new Structs.User
{
    userName = name,
    userSurname = surname
});
```

И получил ошибку

> Null Exception

---

*Как мне это исправить?*

Comment: Что значит "Unity игнорирует массив структур"?

Comment: @RoitBr3aker Юнити выдаёт null при дебаге, массив не появляется в Inspector-е, или же выдаёт ошибку когда я хочу в этом массиве что-то менять.

Comment: Когда он выдает null? Что вы вообще пытаетесь сделать? Сериализовать список структур?

Comment: а вы вообще инициализировали лист?  homeworks = new List<Homework>()

Comment: @Andrey А вот это я не делал. Но я убрал Homeworks лист он опять не сработал

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Я пытался добавить элемент в список Users и получил ошибку `Null Exception`.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker ```Users.Add(new Structs.User{firstname = name, lastname = name}); ``` Вот это я писал

Comment: покажите, пожалуйста, больше кода. И лучше покажите его в вопросе что бы было удобно читать. Там где вы вызываете эти структуры инициализируете и тд. Там где вылазят ошибки

Comment: @Andrey добавил уже

Comment: Users  вы инициализировали этот лист ?

Comment: @Andrey `Users = new List<Structs.User>();` Вы про это?

Comment: @Alt_F4 да, о нем

Comment: @Andrey Да, писал я такое.

Comment: можете приложить полный код скриптов? Или сами файлы. Я попробую сам отдэбажить. А то так не очень понятно

Comment: @Andrey Для полного кода придётся ждать. Сейчас пишу с чужого ноутбука. Дома буду вечером.

Comment: а Structs  висит где то на сцене ?

Comment: @Andrey Нет Structs только в Assets

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100578/discussion-between-andrey-and-alt-f4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Странный ответ у моего вопроса. Ошибку я получил в этой части кода:

```cs
public List<Structs.User> Users;

public void AddButtonClick()
{
    Users = new List<Structs.User>();
    Users.Add(new Structs.User
    {
        userName = userName,
        userSurname = userSurname
    });
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("UsersList", JsonUtility.ToJson(Users));
}
```

---

Как не странно, сделав код вот таким:

```cs
public List<Structs.User> Users = new List<Structs.User>();

public void AddButtonClick()
{
    Users.Add(new Structs.User
    {
        userName = userName,
        userSurname = userSurname
    });
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("UsersList", JsonUtility.ToJson(Users));
}
```

Я исправил все ошибки. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

---

Отдельное спасибо участникам - [RiotBr3aker](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/302909/riotbr3aker), [Andrey](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/315886/andrey), [Yaroslav](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/352119/yaroslav) за уделённое на вопрос внимание.

Answer (score 0):

Вытащи описание структур из класса за его пределы.

```
public struct Homework {
    public int firstPage, secondPage;
    public string description;
    public bool done;

    public Homework (int fp, int sp, string des, bool d) {
        firstPage = fp;
        secondPage = sp;
        description = des;
        done = d;
    }
}

public struct User {
    public string userName, userSurname;
    public List<Homework> Homeworks;

    public User (string name, string surname, List<Homework> hw) {
        userName = name;
        userSurname = surname;
        if (hw == null) { Homeworks = new List<Homework>(); }
        else { Homeworks = hw; }
    }
}

public class YourClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public List<User> Users;

    void Start () {
        Users = new List<User>();

        Unit NewUnitA = new Unit("Stack", "Overflow", null);
        NewUnitA.Homeworks.Add(new Homework(0, 1, "Aa", true));
        NewUnitA.Homeworks.Add(new Homework(1, 2, "Bb", false));
        Users.Add(NewUnitA);

        Unit NewUnitB = new Unit("Stack", "Overflow", new List<Homework>() { new Homework(0, 1, "Aa", true), new Homework(1, 2, "Bb", false) });
        Users.Add(NewUnitB);

        Users.Add(new Unit("Stack", "Overflow", new List<Homework>()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Можете показать пример?

Comment: Это конечно здорово что вы дали мне код который по идее должен работать (пока я не проверял). Но я не хочу просто копировать код. Я бы хотел узнать что я делал не так что вы исправили?

Comment: Сначало сам внимательно, не торопясь глазками соотнеси 'A' с 'B' и только когда что-то будет не ясно спраший. Требовать разжовывание каждой строчки это уже дерзость.

Comment: Я разобрался. Спасибо.